# How to fetch some value from list type of data in json column in oracle table

Tags: sql, arrays, json, oracle, lateral-join

```
[{"clientId":165,"price":125},{"clientId":180,"price":200}]
```

I want a oracle query where i can fetch clientprice based on the clientid.
eg, if clientid=165 then price.

Please help with this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `json_table()` and a lateral join. Assuming that your json array is stored in column `mycol` of table `mycolumn`:

```
select x.*
from mytable t
cross apply json_table(
    t.mycol, '$[*]' columns (
        clientid number path '$.clientId',
        price    number path '$.price'
    )
) x
where x.clientid = 165
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6e7316789377b01629c2b06eba403a36)**:

```
CLIENTID | PRICE
-------: | ----:
     165 |   125
```